# RDBMS VS MAP REDUCE

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was going through Hadoop- The definitive Guide and i came across these lines:

> Normalization poses problems for MapReduce, since it makes reading a record a nonlocal operation, and one of the central assumptions that
>   MapReduce makes is that it is possible to perform (high-speed)
>   streaming reads and writes.

Can someone explain what do these lines actually mean in layman language?

I know what is Normalization. How does it make makes reading a record a nonlocal
operation? What is the meaning of a non local operation in reference to hadoop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In hadoop a local operation refers to executing code in the same physical location where the data it needs to work with is being stored.

When you normalize your data you're essentially splitting it up. If this "split up" data gets distributed in 2 physically different areas you suddenly have non-local operations.

Comment: Alright. So the point is Hadoop just makes duplicate copies of the data through replication and then it can process the data at a faster rate as compared to RDBMS Normalization.

Comment: Although hadoop does replication, the real purpose of map-reduce is that you could split a data-set and process each part in parallel on its own machine.

Comment: The ability to split data over multiple machines is called horizontal scaling.